# Get username of facebook django all auth

Tags: python, django, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have made an application using django all-auth. I have following variables set:-

```
SITE_ID = 1
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = "username_email"
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_EXPIRE_DAYS = 7
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = "none"
ACCOUNT_UNIQUE_EMAIL = True
ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_PASSWORD_VERIFICATION = True
SOCIALACCOUNT_AUTO_SIGNUP = True
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "/home/"
ACCOUNT_LOGOUT_ON_GET = True
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_BLACKLIST =[]
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False

SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    'facebook': {
        'SCOPE': [
            "email",
            "user_friends"
            ],
        #'AUTH_PARAMS': { 'auth_type': 'reauthenticate' },
        'AUTH_PARAMS': { },
        'METHOD': 'oauth2'
        },
    }
```

The problem is django all auth doesnot save the username of facebook user as in facebook. It takes the frist name. How can I make the allauth to save the username of facebook during signup.

Answer (score 0):

Hope it's not too late for you. What you would want to do is hook up to the `allauth.socialaccount.signals.social_account_added` signal, and use the Facebook Graph API to translate the allauth social account `id` entry into a Facebook handle/username.

See [django-allauth docs (signals)](http://django-allauth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/signals.html#allauth-socialaccount) and [user accounts on facebook graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/accounts/)